# If $(X, \tau_1)$ is connected and $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$, then is $(X, \tau_2)$ neccessarily connected?

Tags: general-topology

> If $(X, \tau_1)$ is connected and $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$, then is $(X, \tau_2)$ neccessarily connected?

Since If $(X, \tau_1)$ is connected, there does not exists disjoint $A, B$ open in $\tau_1$ such that $X= A \cup B$, but since $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$ this doesn't mean that $\tau_2$ wouldn't have disjoint open sets $D, E$ for which $X= D \cup E$?

Take for example $X= \Bbb R$ and $\tau_1$ be the standard topolgy and $\tau_2$ the lower limit topology. $(X, \tau_1)$ is connected and $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$, but $(X, \tau_2)$ isn't connected as $\Bbb R = (-\infty, 0] \cup (0, \infty)$, would this work as counterexample?

Also is $(0, \infty)$ open in the lower limit topology?

Comment: Hint. Discrete topology is finer than every topology.

Comment: the other way around is correct, that is, $(X,T_2)$ is connected and $T_1\subset T_2$ then $(X, T_1)$ is connected as well. To see that, just take an identity function from $(X,T_2)$   to  $(X,T_1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take any set $X$ with at least two elements. Consider the trivial topology $\tau_1$  on $X$ and let $\tau_2$ be the discrete topology on $X$. Then $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ and $(X, \tau_1)$ is connected, while $(X, \tau_2)$ is not.

The converse does hold, that is if $(X, \tau_2)$ is connected, then $(X, \tau_1)$ is connected provided that $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2.$

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting counter example.

Consider, $\Bbb{R}$ with $\tau_{eucidean}$ and $\tau_{lower\space limit}$.

Then it is easy to verify $\tau_{eucidean}$ is strictly coarser than $\tau_{lower\space limit}$. i.e $\tau_{euclidean} \subset \tau_{lower\space limit}$.

$(\Bbb{R},\tau_{euclidean}) $ is connected but $(\Bbb{R},\tau_{lower\space limit }) $ is not connected. (Try to prove! )